# how can I disable checkboxes in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to disable a checkbox input, I mean, the user can not check de checkbox

there is an atribute to disable this? like [enable] or [disable]? or how can I fix this?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="isActive"  [(ngModel)]="user.isActive">
```

any idea?

Comment: The `disabled` attribute is probably what you're looking for...were you looking to bind that to an event?

Comment: @Makoto You should write that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Kody:  Since I'm asking a question to the OP...no, I really shouldn't leave that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To disable a checkbox, I tried many [disabled], [attr.disabled]

But interpolation worked.

```
<input name="chkUpdate" type="checkbox" 
       [(ngModel)]="selectedGrp.Updateind" 
       disabled="{{selectedGrp.App_Id == 5}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation didn't work for me, had to set disabled on FormControl:

```
new FormControl({value: value, disabled: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using reactive forms, you can use something like this in the right methods:

To disable:

```
this.myform.controls['chkUpdate'].disable();
```

To enable:

```
this.myform.controls['chkUpdate'].enable();
```