# how to disable input from component in Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on Angular 5 application. I have reactive form which are all working fine. Now I have requirement to disable input when user click on checkbox true.. all is working fine expect I want to know how to disable input from component. I successfully get id of input but not sure what do next???

### component

```
private handleQuestionAnswerProvidedStateChange(questionAnswerProvidedState:QuestionAnswerProvidedStateDataModel)
{
  console.log(">>>>>>> questionAnswerProvidedStateEvent ",questionAnswerProvidedState);
  var elementReference = document.getElementById(questionAnswerProvidedState.QuestionId);
  console.log("elementReference ",elementReference);
}
```

### template

```
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"> <small>textbox</small>
           <div class="form-group">
               <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" 
                      [formControlName]="question.key" 
                      [id]="question.key" 
                      [type]="question.type"
                      [(ngModel)]="question.value" 
                      (keyup.enter)="onChangeValue($event, previousValue, responseId, question.key, 'textbox'); previousValue = question.value" 
                      (blur)="onChangeValue($event,  previousValue, responseId, question.key, 'textbox'); previousValue = question.value"
                      (focus)="previousValue=question.value"
                      >
           </div>            
       </div>
```

following text is loop, so there will many input each with unique id

Comment: Use `ViewChild()` for input element in the component file and set `disabled = true`

Comment: in your typescript code, test your checkbox, if it is checked then disable the input field

Comment: do something like this :

`if (document.getElementById("CheckBoxId").checked == true){
 document.getElementById("textFieldId").disabled = true;
}`

Comment: look for Pipe+ReactiveForm+Disable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create template reference `#inputEl` for input element and use it in component file.

```
<div class="form-group">
                   <input #inputEl
                          *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" 
                          [formControlName]="question.key" 
                          [id]="question.key" 
                          [type]="question.type"
                          [(ngModel)]="question.value" 
                          (keyup.enter)="onChangeValue($event, previousValue, responseId, question.key, 'textbox'); previousValue = question.value" 
                          (blur)="onChangeValue($event,  previousValue, responseId, question.key, 'textbox'); previousValue = question.value"
                          (focus)="previousValue=question.value"
                          >
               </div>
```

Create a property using `ViewChild()` for input element in the component .ts file and set `disabled = true`

component.ts

```
@ViewChild('inputEl') public inputEl: ElementRef;

fun() {
  this.inputEl.nativeElement.disabled = true;
}
```

EDIT :

Since the inputs are generated dynamically and the id of each element is being fetched.

Following should help:

`document.getElementById(questionAnswerProvidedState.QuestionId).setAttribute('disabled', 'true');`

Comment: I have many input type like radio, checkbox and customs.... using ##inputEl reference will restrict my code or?? is there more generic way to achieve this or using javascript

Comment: Are they all dynamic?

Comment: yes they are all dynamically generated ... but each with unique GUID id

Comment: document.getElementById(questionAnswerProvidedState.QuestionId) brings back correct reference of html input

Comment: Then did you try this `document.getElementById(questionAnswerProvidedState.QuestionId).setAttribute('disabled', 'true');`

Comment: got answer and posted below

Answer (score 0):

got answer....

```
private handleQuestionAnswerProvidedStateChange(questionAnswerProvidedState:QuestionAnswerProvidedStateDataModel)
{
  console.log(">>>>>>> questionAnswerProvidedStateEvent ",questionAnswerProvidedState);
  if(questionAnswerProvidedState!=null)
  {
    var elementReference = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById(questionAnswerProvidedState.QuestionId);
    if(questionAnswerProvidedState.AnswerNotProvided == true)
    {
      elementReference.disabled = true;
    }
    else if(questionAnswerProvidedState.AnswerNotProvided == false)
    {
      elementReference.disabled = false;
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: That's weird code. I thought you were using reactive forms?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500683/how-can-i-disable-checkboxes-in-angular-2